# If data has Number of features greater than number of samples, will it always be linearly separable?

Tags: svm

According to a corollary using VC dimension, n+1 points can always be shattered in [image]. Hence, if the feature space dimension is far greater than the number of samples, there will always be a hyperplane that can separate two classes.

So, if I have 50 samples and 100 features, they will always be linearly separable. Is this conclusion right?

Comment: Assuming no collinearity/cohyperplanarity problems? You'll never find a hyperplane with `(0, 0, ..., 1)` on one side and `(0, 0, ..., 0)` and `(0, 0, ..., 2)` on the other, no matter how many extra features you add.

Comment: But I have only two classes. It's a binary classification problem @user2357112

Comment: And my example is a binary classification problem.

Comment: Thanks, got it! could you add this as an answer? @user2357112